# Issue with to get data from MongoDB aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I want data from places where `userid` is equal to the `body.user._id`

**PLACE DATA**

```
{
            "_id": "5e8ddd0f7f5b174290bbefc8",
            "type": 0,
            "location": [
                24.8757396,
                67.3464698
            ],
            "title": "E 22, Steel Town Karachi, Karachi City, Sindh, Pakistan",
            "googlePlaceId": "ChIJlbvA8BIzsz4Rlh7w_fKfwus",
            "createdDate": "2020-04-08T14:17:51.869Z",
            "__v": 0,
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e8de4204396310017564a2b",
            "type": 0,
            "location": [
                24.910688,
                67.0310973
            ],
            "title": "Nazimabad, Karachi, Pakistan",
            "googlePlaceId": "ChIJzZudRr0_sz4R81KZ48Ylk3Q",
            "createdDate": "2020-04-08T14:48:00.557Z",
            "__v": 0,
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e8de4364396310017564a2d",
            "type": 0,
            "location": [
                24.9180271,
                67.0970916
            ],
            "title": "Gulshan-e-Iqbal, Karachi, Pakistan",
            "googlePlaceId": "ChIJsda_CLg4sz4RIghXwgIae5k",
            "createdDate": "2020-04-08T14:48:22.979Z",
            "__v": 0,
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e8dea79894854524cc554e0",
            "type": 0,
            "location": [
                24.9343322,
                67.177173
            ],
            "title": "Malir Cantt Check Post No 6, Malir Link to Super Highway, Karachi, Pakistan",
            "googlePlaceId": "ChIJJ7BbsyQ4sz4RvpkV9Ig_aU4",
            "createdDate": "2020-04-08T15:15:05.360Z",
            "__v": 0,
        }**
```

**Visited Places DATA**

```
{
    "_id":"5e90998f8bc84d0017a6d2f3",
    "visitingNo":"0",
    "_userId":"5e8f3ef5434f5800170c7169"
    "_placeId":"5e908fdb8bc84d0017a6d2e8"
    "createdDate":"2020-04-10T16:06:39.231+00:00"
    "__v":"0"
},
    
{
    "_id":"5e90998f8bc84d0017a6d2f3",
    "visitingNo":"0",
    "_userId":"5e8f3ef5434f5800170c7169"
    "_placeId":"5e908fdb8bc84d0017a6d2e8"
    "createdDate":"2020-04-10T16:06:39.231+00:00"
    "__v":"0"
},
{
    "_id":"5e90998f8bc84d0017a6d2f3",
    "visitingNo":"0",
    "_userId":"5e8f3ef5434f5800170c7169"
    "_placeId":"5e908fdb8bc84d0017a6d2e8"
    "createdDate":"2020-04-10T16:06:39.231+00:00"
    "__v":"0"
},
```

MY CODE

```
  const palace = placeData.aggregate([
   {
 
    $lookup:{
    from: `${visitplaceData}`,
    // localField: "_id",
    // foreignField: "_placeId",
    let : {
      "placeId" : "$_id"
  },
    pipeline : [
      { $sort: { visitingNo : -1 } },
      {
          $match : {
              $expr : {
                  $and : [
                    {$eq: [ "$_placeId", "$$placeId" ]},
                    {"_userId": body.user._id}
                  ]
              }
          }
      },
  ],

    as: "places"
  }
}
 ])
```